# "uninstall-Package : No project was specified" Error

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am getting this error when I try to uninstall a package with this command.

"Uninstall-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation".

and I get the error "uninstall-Package : No project was specified"

There is only one project in the solution

Answer (score 0):

I changed the command to "Uninstall-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation -Project project-name".

This was optional as per the reference given here. But for me, it was mandatory. https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference